# Errors while compiling publisher and subscriber from ros2_examples

Tags: ros2, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu Version: 18.04
Ros2 Crystal is installed and sourced.
Step1:
The examples in ros2 is cloned from the following link
https://github.com/ros2/examples
Step2:
The folders other than "minimal_publisher" and "minimal_subscriber" is removed.

Step 3:
colcon build --symlink-install command is given

Following error appears:

```
**Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher                                                                                                
CMakeFiles/publisher_not_composable.dir/not_composable.cpp.o: In function `rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> >::Publisher(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_publisher_options_t const&, std::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > > > const&)':
not_composable.cpp:(.text._ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC2EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE[_ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC5EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE]+0x22): undefined reference to `rosidl_message_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_message_type_support_handle<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [publisher_not_composable] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/publisher_not_composable.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/publisher_lambda.dir/lambda.cpp.o: In function `rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> >::Publisher(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_publisher_options_t const&, std::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > > > const&)':
lambda.cpp:(.text._ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC2EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE[_ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC5EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE]+0x22): undefined reference to `rosidl_message_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_message_type_support_handle<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [publisher_lambda] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/publisher_lambda.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/publisher_member_function.dir/member_function.cpp.o: In function `rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> >::Publisher(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_publisher_options_t const&, std::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > > > const&)':
member_function.cpp:(.text._ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC2EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE[_ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC5EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE]+0x22): undefined reference to `rosidl_message_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_message_type_support_handle<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [publisher_member_function] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/publisher_member_function.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher  [ Exited with code 2 ]
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber                                         
CMakeFiles/subscriber_lambda.dir/lambda.cpp.o: In function `rclcpp::create_subscription_factory<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, MinimalSubscriber::MinimalSubscriber()::{lambda(std::unique_ptr<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::default_delete<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > > >)#1}, std::allocator<void>, std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, rclcpp::Subscription<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> > >(MinimalSubscriber::MinimalSubscriber()::{lambda(std::unique_ptr<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::default_delete<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > > >)#1}&&, rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> >::SharedPtr, std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >)::{lambda(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_subscription_options_t&)#1}::operator()(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rcl_subscription_options_t) const':
lambda.cpp:(.text._ZZN6rclcpp27create_subscription_factoryIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEEZN17MinimalSubscriberC4EvEUlSt10unique_ptrIS5_St14default_deleteIS5_EEE_S4_S5_NS_12SubscriptionIS5_S4_EEEENS_19SubscriptionFactoryEOT0_NS_23message_memory_strategy21MessageMemoryStrategyIT2_T1_E9SharedPtrESt10shared_ptrISK_EENKUlPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEER26rcl_subscription_options_tE_clESR_SZ_S11_[_ZZN6rclcpp27create_subscription_factoryIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEEZN17MinimalSubscriberC4EvEUlSt10unique_ptrIS5_St14default_deleteIS5_EEE_S4_S5_NS_12SubscriptionIS5_S4_EEEENS_19SubscriptionFactoryEOT0_NS_23message_memory_strategy21MessageMemoryStrategyIT2_T1_E9SharedPtrESt10shared_ptrISK_EENKUlPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEER26rcl_subscription_options_tE_clESR_SZ_S11_]+0xa6): undefined reference to `rosidl_message_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_message_type_support_handle<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [subscriber_lambda] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/subscriber_lambda.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/subscriber_not_composable.dir/not_composable.cpp.o: In function `rclcpp::create_subscription_factory<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, void (&)(std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >), std::allocator<void>, std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, rclcpp::Subscription<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> > >(void (&)(std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >), rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> >::SharedPtr, std::shared_ptr<std::allocator<void> >)::{lambda(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_subscription_options_t&)#1}::operator()(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_subscription_options_t&) const':
not_composable.cpp:(.text._ZZN6rclcpp27create_subscription_factoryIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEERFvSt10shared_ptrIS5_EES4_S5_NS_12SubscriptionIS5_S4_EEEENS_19SubscriptionFactoryEOT0_NS_23message_memory_strategy21MessageMemoryStrategyIT2_T1_E9SharedPtrES6_ISI_EENKUlPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEER26rcl_subscription_options_tE_clESO_SW_SY_[_ZZN6rclcpp27create_subscription_factoryIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEERFvSt10shared_ptrIS5_EES4_S5_NS_12SubscriptionIS5_S4_EEEENS_19SubscriptionFactoryEOT0_NS_23message_memory_strategy21MessageMemoryStrategyIT2_T1_E9SharedPtrES6_ISI_EENKUlPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEER26rcl_subscription_options_tE_clESO_SW_SY_]+0xa6): undefined reference to `rosidl_message_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_message_type_support_handle<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [subscriber_not_composable] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/subscriber_not_composable.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/subscriber_member_function.dir/member_function.cpp.o: In function `rclcpp::create_subscription_factory<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::_Bind<void (MinimalSubscriber::*(MinimalSubscriber*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >)>, std::allocator<void>, std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, rclcpp::Subscription<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> > >(std::_Bind<void (MinimalSubscriber::*(MinimalSubscriber*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >)>&&, rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> >::SharedPtr, std::shared_ptr<std::allocator<void> >)::{lambda(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_subscription_options_t&)#1}::operator()(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_subscription_options_t&) const':
member_function.cpp:(.text._ZZN6rclcpp27create_subscription_factoryIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEESt5_BindIFM17MinimalSubscriberFvSt10shared_ptrIS5_EEPS7_St12_PlaceholderILi1EEEES4_S5_NS_12SubscriptionIS5_S4_EEEENS_19SubscriptionFactoryEOT0_NS_23message_memory_strategy21MessageMemoryStrategyIT2_T1_E9SharedPtrES8_ISP_EENKUlPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEER26rcl_subscription_options_tE_clESV_S13_S15_[_ZZN6rclcpp27create_subscription_factoryIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEESt5_BindIFM17MinimalSubscriberFvSt10shared_ptrIS5_EEPS7_St12_PlaceholderILi1EEEES4_S5_NS_12SubscriptionIS5_S4_EEEENS_19SubscriptionFactoryEOT0_NS_23message_memory_strategy21MessageMemoryStrategyIT2_T1_E9SharedPtrES8_ISP_EENKUlPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEER26rcl_subscription_options_tE_clESV_S13_S15_]+0xa6): undefined reference to `rosidl_message_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_message_type_support_handle<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [subscriber_member_function] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/subscriber_member_function.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
---
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber

Summary: 0 packages finished [5.60s]
  1 package failed: examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher
  1 package aborted: examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber
  2 packages had stderr output: examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber
**

Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher                                                                                                
CMakeFiles/publisher_not_composable.dir/not_composable.cpp.o: In function `rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> >::Publisher(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_publisher_options_t const&, std::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > > > const&)':
not_composable.cpp:(.text._ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC2EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE[_ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC5EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE]+0x22): undefined reference to `rosidl_message_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_message_type_support_handle<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [publisher_not_composable] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/publisher_not_composable.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/publisher_lambda.dir/lambda.cpp.o: In function `rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> >::Publisher(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_publisher_options_t const&, std::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > > > const&)':
lambda.cpp:(.text._ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC2EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE[_ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC5EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE]+0x22): undefined reference to `rosidl_message_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_message_type_support_handle<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [publisher_lambda] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/publisher_lambda.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/publisher_member_function.dir/member_function.cpp.o: In function `rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> >::Publisher(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_publisher_options_t const&, std::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > > > const&)':
member_function.cpp:(.text._ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC2EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE[_ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC5EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE]+0x22): undefined reference to `rosidl_message_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_message_type_support_handle<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [publisher_member_function] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/publisher_member_function.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher  [ Exited with code 2 ]
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber                                         
CMakeFiles/subscriber_lambda.dir/lambda.cpp.o: In function `rclcpp::create_subscription_factory<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, MinimalSubscriber::MinimalSubscriber()::{lambda(std::unique_ptr<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::default_delete<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > > >)#1}, std::allocator<void>, std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, rclcpp::Subscription<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> > >(MinimalSubscriber::MinimalSubscriber()::{lambda(std::unique_ptr<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::default_delete<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > > >)#1}&&, rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> >::SharedPtr, std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >)::{lambda(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_subscription_options_t&)#1}::operator()(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, rcl_subscription_options_t) const':
lambda.cpp:(.text._ZZN6rclcpp27create_subscription_factoryIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEEZN17MinimalSubscriberC4EvEUlSt10unique_ptrIS5_St14default_deleteIS5_EEE_S4_S5_NS_12SubscriptionIS5_S4_EEEENS_19SubscriptionFactoryEOT0_NS_23message_memory_strategy21MessageMemoryStrategyIT2_T1_E9SharedPtrESt10shared_ptrISK_EENKUlPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEER26rcl_subscription_options_tE_clESR_SZ_S11_[_ZZN6rclcpp27create_subscription_factoryIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEEZN17MinimalSubscriberC4EvEUlSt10unique_ptrIS5_St14default_deleteIS5_EEE_S4_S5_NS_12SubscriptionIS5_S4_EEEENS_19SubscriptionFactoryEOT0_NS_23message_memory_strategy21MessageMemoryStrategyIT2_T1_E9SharedPtrESt10shared_ptrISK_EENKUlPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEER26rcl_subscription_options_tE_clESR_SZ_S11_]+0xa6): undefined reference to `rosidl_message_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_message_type_support_handle<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [subscriber_lambda] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/subscriber_lambda.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/subscriber_not_composable.dir/not_composable.cpp.o: In function `rclcpp::create_subscription_factory<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, void (&)(std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >), std::allocator<void>, std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, rclcpp::Subscription<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> > >(void (&)(std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >), rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> >::SharedPtr, std::shared_ptr<std::allocator<void> >)::{lambda(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_subscription_options_t&)#1}::operator()(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_subscription_options_t&) const':
not_composable.cpp:(.text._ZZN6rclcpp27create_subscription_factoryIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEERFvSt10shared_ptrIS5_EES4_S5_NS_12SubscriptionIS5_S4_EEEENS_19SubscriptionFactoryEOT0_NS_23message_memory_strategy21MessageMemoryStrategyIT2_T1_E9SharedPtrES6_ISI_EENKUlPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEER26rcl_subscription_options_tE_clESO_SW_SY_[_ZZN6rclcpp27create_subscription_factoryIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEERFvSt10shared_ptrIS5_EES4_S5_NS_12SubscriptionIS5_S4_EEEENS_19SubscriptionFactoryEOT0_NS_23message_memory_strategy21MessageMemoryStrategyIT2_T1_E9SharedPtrES6_ISI_EENKUlPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEER26rcl_subscription_options_tE_clESO_SW_SY_]+0xa6): undefined reference to `rosidl_message_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_message_type_support_handle<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [subscriber_not_composable] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/subscriber_not_composable.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/subscriber_member_function.dir/member_function.cpp.o: In function `rclcpp::create_subscription_factory<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::_Bind<void (MinimalSubscriber::*(MinimalSubscriber*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >)>, std::allocator<void>, std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, rclcpp::Subscription<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> > >(std::_Bind<void (MinimalSubscriber::*(MinimalSubscriber*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >)>&&, rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> >::SharedPtr, std::shared_ptr<std::allocator<void> >)::{lambda(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_subscription_options_t&)#1}::operator()(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_subscription_options_t&) const':
member_function.cpp:(.text._ZZN6rclcpp27create_subscription_factoryIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEESt5_BindIFM17MinimalSubscriberFvSt10shared_ptrIS5_EEPS7_St12_PlaceholderILi1EEEES4_S5_NS_12SubscriptionIS5_S4_EEEENS_19SubscriptionFactoryEOT0_NS_23message_memory_strategy21MessageMemoryStrategyIT2_T1_E9SharedPtrES8_ISP_EENKUlPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEER26rcl_subscription_options_tE_clESV_S13_S15_[_ZZN6rclcpp27create_subscription_factoryIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEESt5_BindIFM17MinimalSubscriberFvSt10shared_ptrIS5_EEPS7_St12_PlaceholderILi1EEEES4_S5_NS_12SubscriptionIS5_S4_EEEENS_19SubscriptionFactoryEOT0_NS_23message_memory_strategy21MessageMemoryStrategyIT2_T1_E9SharedPtrES8_ISP_EENKUlPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEER26rcl_subscription_options_tE_clESV_S13_S15_]+0xa6): undefined reference to `rosidl_message_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_message_type_support_handle<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [subscriber_member_function] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/subscriber_member_function.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
---
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber

Summary: 0 packages finished [5.60s]
  1 package failed: examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher
  1 package aborted: examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber
  2 packages had stderr output: examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321275/errors-while-compiling-publisher-and-subscriber-from-ros2_examples/) by [Abirami_Ravi](https://answers.ros.org/users/40846/abirami_ravi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2019-04-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-17**:\

> Errors while running

these appear to be compiler errors. Not runtime errors. Is that correct?

**Comment by [Abirami_Ravi](https://answers.ros.org/users/40846/abirami_ravi/) on 2019-04-17**:
Yes these are compiler errors

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-17**:
Then it would seem the current title of your question is incorrect.

I've updated it to reflect your problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just tested your example (first removing most directories) and it compiles & links fine for me. Having said that, I see that there's a `crystal` branch on https://github.com/ros2/examples, so you probably want to git checkout that branch.

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2019-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0